# How to retrieve request controller, action and module name in a model or Using Service Manager (Zend framework 2)?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've a model in which I've log request details. But i'm unable to find a way to retrieve request details in model. I do have receiving Service manager in model constructor.

This is my model where I need to get module, controller and action.

```
class LogHelpModel {

    //$sm is the service manager.
    public function __construct($sm) {
        //How to retrieve module/controller/action here ?
    }
}
```

Following is my module config.

```
public function getServiceConfig() {

    return array(
        'factories' => array(

            Application\Model\LogHelpModel' => function($sm) {
                return new LogHelpModel($sm) ;
            },

        )
    );
}
```

How to get those details in model (or using $sm) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get mvc event then routematch object then event in zf3. Polly is same in zf2 too.  Here's zf3 code:

```
$sm->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRoutMatch()
```

This' s Thé object you're looking for.

ps: sorry no code blocks in mobile phone.

Comment: it dint worked, this worked. $sm->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch() ;

Comment: Oh you right. GetApplication MvcEvent's method. Your way is the way to get appliaction from container.